# Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally

Tags: npm, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to install `aws-azure-login`. I have to follow with Linux -> `Option B: Install Only for Current User`.
Then I ran this command:

```sh
sudo npm install -g aws-azure-login
```

I've got this output here:

```sh
GGNXFB3:~$ sudo npm install -g aws-azure-login

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
/usr/local/bin/aws-azure-login -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/lib/index.js

> puppeteer@10.2.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r901912! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium']
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path:
   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium' }
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for aws-azure-login@3.4.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.0"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: aws-azure-login@3.4.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for commander@8.1.0: wanted: {"node":">= 12"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: commander@8.1.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@10.2.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@10.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-18T00_37_04_178Z-debug.log
GGNXFB3:~$
```

Anyone has had success with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure about the [following things](https://github.com/sportradar/aws-azure-login#linux) first:

1. **Upgrade your Node.Js** from `10.19.0` to `>=12.0`
2. Check if you have done the **puppeteer dependency installation** before npm installing `aws-azure-login`.

The list of required packages is listed here on [puppeteer's Troubleshooting document](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix) per Linux system (Debian or CentOS). E.g.:

```sh
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 ...
```

(But make sure you add all the relevant packages!)